# Do skills exist in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

I need to know if the abilities like spot, swim, move silently, and stuff like that exist in dungeons and dragons 5th edition.

I really am confused about this. I know that there are skills like this when you make you character such as athletics and acrobatics, but I really don't know if that's the same thing.

I'm playing as a monk and I know that in previous games you could be proficient in the diplomacy skill, and spot, but i can't find any of that in the new guides.

Comment: I'm confused why you're confused. You say you know there are "skills like this when you make you[r] character". What part of this is confusing you?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what the questioner is asking here. There are things that were skills in earlier editions that are now more like applications of different, broader skills. As a new person, they're presumably trying to avoid making a character a certain way and finding out once in play that they're missing some key thing.

Comment: @Polisurgist Well, they're starting out with the flat-out question "Do skills exist?" If they're asking a question that contradicts itself, even if the rest of the question seems clear, that indicates that there's some kind of disconnect. Without more information, we can only guess what that disconnect is. So: hold until more information.

Comment: Jake, please edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking, and it can be reopened.

Answer (score 10):

Spot has been replaced by a combination of Perception and Investigation.
Perception is for noticing things about you, people sneaking up and such. Investigation is for searching for things in a room or researching things.

Swim is covered by Athletics.

Move Silently is now covered by Stealth skill.

Everyone is capable of performing each skill. If you choose it as a proficiency you get to add your proficiency bonus to the roll, otherwise it's simply 1d20 + stat modifier.

The skill section explains each skill pretty clearly. Anything else that is not linkable to a skill is assigned to a relevant stat check by DM's decision.